# JSF Input Page with Datatable

Tags: jsf-2

Kindly excuse me if this question has already been answered somwhere. I am unable to trace it.
I want to create an input page with a submit button. Each time some value is input and the submit button is click ,it in turn update my datatable with these values.

i am able to retrieve the input values in my managed Bean. I know also how to create a datatable and bind it to a managed bean.

What i dnt know is how to update the managed bean which is used to create the datatable each time the submit button is clicked.

For info i am using JSF 2.0

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Just do `dataTableValue.add(inputValue)` in action?

Comment: Hi Balsusc. how do i inject the dataTableValue in the action class?

Comment: You said you already know how to create data table and bind it to bean? It looks like `<h:dataTable value="#{bean.dataTableValue}">`, right? The input then looks like `<h:inputText value="#{bean.inputValue}">`, right?

Comment: Hi Balusc..Yes that i know..Maybe i need to explain again..I have two managed bean.One is viewscope for the input form and one is sessionscope for the datable. now on submit on the input form it goes on an action (in the viewscope bena) which take the value of the viewscope bean and need to update the session scope beans.So my question is how do i inject the sessionscope bean on the viewscope bean so as i can update it..